# Schneider Micom P123 trigger Output Relay

Tags: relay, protocol

I am testing a Micom P123 relay with IEC103 protocol. I was able to communicate with 3rd party free Protocol Analyzer, Vinci. I was able to get Digital Input status. So communications is working good. The problem is I cannot trigger any of the output relay (there are 8 relays in this device). Specification for Control Direction is as follow (which is very vague for me):

```
General Commands (ASDU 20) (Control direction): Availability
− Auto-recloser On / Off: only on MiCOM P123: P123
FUN<160>;INF<16>, TYP<20>, COT <20>
− LEDs Reset: This command acknowledge all alarms on Front Panel on MiCOM P12x products:
FUN<160>;INF<19>, TYP<20>, COT <20>,<ADDR> P120 to P123
− Setting group number 1: FUN<160>;INF<23>, TYP<20>, COT <20>,<ADDR> P122-P123
− Setting group number 2: FUN<160>;INF<24>, TYP<20>, COT <20>,<ADDR> P122-P123
− Order TC COMM1: FUN<168>;INF <234>; TYP <20>; COT<20>,<ADDR> P122-P123
with private option inactive: FUN<160>;INF <136>; TYP <1>; COT<20>,<ADDR>
− Order TC COMM2: FUN<168>;INF <235>; TYP <20>; COT<20>,<ADDR> P122-P123
with private option inactive: FUN<160>;INF <137>; TYP <1>; COT<20>,<ADDR>
− Order TC COMM3: FUN<168>;INF <238>; TYP <20>; COT<20>,<ADDR> P122-P123
with private option inactive: FUN<160>;INF <138>; TYP <1>; COT<20>,<ADDR>
− Order TC COMM4: FUN<168>;INF <239>; TYP <20>; COT<20>,<ADDR> P122-P123
with private option inactive: FUN<160>;INF <139>; TYP <1>; COT<20>,<ADDR>
− Trip TC: FUN<168>;INF <1>; TYP <20>; COT<20>,<ADDR> P120 to P123
with private option inactive: FUN<160>;INF <142>; TYP <1>; COT<20>,<ADDR>
− Close TC: FUN<168>;INF <2>; TYP <20>; COT<20>,<ADDR> P120 to P123
with private option inactive: FUN<160>;INF <143>; TYP <1>; COT<20>,<ADDR>
After executing one of these commands, the relay sends an acknowledge message, which contains the result of command execution.
If a state change is the consequence of the command, it must be sent in a ASDU 1 with COT 12 (remote operation).
If the relay receive another command message from the master station before sending the acknowledge message, it will be discarded.
Commands which are not processed by the relay are rejected with a negative acknowledge message.
```

I tried Sending Fun 160, Inf 143, but still nothing. Tried asking Schneider too, but they are pretty much unhelpful to the max. If anyone has experience on this, pls do share. Thanks.

Comment: i do not know anything about the relay that you are fighting with ..... i noticed this in the printout `If a state change is the consequence of the command, it must be sent in a ASDU 1 with COT 12 (remote operation).`

Comment: and what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is still interested, I managed to trigger the relay. I guess the problem was, my own lack of knowledge on how these relays work. Basically, in each of these devices, there are built FUNCTIONS which we can program/assign which of the 8 relays to trigger. And it is assignable using the device's front panel.

For example, to use Trip TC and Close TC function, we can goto the front panel menu and set the bit for each of the relay. Lets say, under Trip TC function, I want to turn on, relay 3,4 and 5. So under the menu:

```
Close TC
87654321
00011100
```

Then, when we send command to this function Address (func: inf: no: ), then all three relays will turn ON. To turn them off, assign the following to another function and send command to it.

```
Trip TC
87654321
00000000
```

That's all.